# Abs(0.33-0.99)=0.6599999999 Why?

Tags: java, floating-point, absolute

While running `kmeans` clustering in `java` the absolute difference between the data points 0.33 and 0.99 is displayed as 0.659999999 instead of 0.66.

Why is that?

Both the variables holding the data are of type `double` and I am using the `Math.abs()` function.

I saw such a problem only for 0.99. When subtracting using other values, the results were fine.

Thanks for any help

Comment: See [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) - the article is from the Python docs, but the issue is language-independent. Binary floating points can't accurately store decimal floating point numbers in many cases.

Comment: This video explains this very well. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0

Comment: @Jakob: Even your abacus (and your fingers+toes too) have only a finite number of bits available ;-P

Comment: @JensG yes but adding using my fingers gives correct results, and not 1 finger + 1 finger = 1.99999899 fingers :)

Comment: Never ever never, no matter what forever!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating-point datatype (float and double) can't be accurately represented in memory bits. They are approximately represented in memory.

> Squeezing infinitely many real numbers into a finite number of bits
>   requires an approximate representation. Although there are infinitely
>   many integers, in most programs the result of integer computations can
>   be stored in 32 bits. In contrast, given any fixed number of bits,
>   most calculations with real numbers will produce quantities that
>   cannot be exactly represented using that many bits. Therefore the
>   result of a floating-point calculation must often be rounded in order
>   to fit back into its finite representation. This rounding error is the
>   characteristic feature of floating-point computation

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: If you don't mind, can you explain why `Math.abs(new Float(0.33-0.99))` return `0.66` instead?

Answer (score 2):

This is how floating point numbers behave. They are not accurate.

Check this:- **[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)**

Also to add Floating point numbers use binary fractions and not decimal fractions. And if you need exact decimal values, you should use `java.math.BigDecimal`

You may check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) as well for more reasoning and details:

> Floating point rounding errors. 0.1 cannot be represented as
>   accurately in base-2 as in base-10 due to the missing prime factor of
>   5.

Answer (score 1):

Doubles are not exact due to the way they are stored in memory. More information here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

If you need an exact result, you should look into [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: BigDecimal is no more exact than `double`. It is only exact for a different set of numbers.

Comment: Could you back that claim up? Because, as far as I know, BigDecimal IS more exact.

From the documentation: "When a MathContext object is supplied with a precision setting of 0 (for example, MathContext.UNLIMITED), arithmetic operations are exact, as are the arithmetic methods which take no MathContext object."

Comment: Note: I didn't say it wasn't “more exact”. I said it was exact for a different set of numbers than `double` (`double` is exact for lots of numbers and it is possible to do long sequences of exact `double` computations if you know what you are doing), and that “If you need an exact result, you should look into BigDecimal” was a mischaracterization. Let me put it this way: I would like the exact result of 1 divided by 3. It is a waste of time to “look into BigDecimal” for this elementary operation. It won't work.

Comment: Point taken. "In the case of divide, the exact quotient could have an infinitely long decimal expansion; for example, 1 divided by 3. If the quotient has a nonterminating decimal expansion and the operation is specified to return an exact result, an ArithmeticException is thrown." - However, you can specify the amount of decimals you want to see (up to 4679 digits, what I've tested), making it far more exact than a Double.

Comment: You mean “far more precise than a double”. Either a representation is exact or it isn't.